# How to modify an image before saving it in the database in Django?

Tags: python, django

I took an image as the input by the user via a form, I increased its brightness using Pillow, and now wish to save the image in the database. I am having trouble trying to modify the form with the new image so that I can save it. Please help me out.

```
if form.is_valid():
            input = form.save(commit=False)
            input.owner = request.user
            
            image = Image.open(input.image)
            # Enhance Brightness
            curr_bri = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
            new_bri = 2.5
            # Brightness enhanced by a factor of 2.5
            img_brightened = curr_bri.enhance(new_bri)
            image_file = ImageFile(img_brightened, name=None)
            form_image = ImageClient(image=image_file)
            input.image = form_image
            
            input.save()
            return redirect('profile')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You may get an error when you submit this form: `"image was wrong mode"` the error is typically occurs when you're trying to perform operations on an image that is in a mode not supported by the operation. In the context of Pillow, the image mode refers to the color representation of the image (e.g., RGB, grayscale, etc.), In this case you have to convert the image to RGB.

Secondly, the image may never be saved to the database because the library was programmatically created to save an image inside your project directory. I Added some code in the views that could save the image to the database.

Thirdly, you did not add your models.py file. Let's assume you have a model called Image with one field called 'image'.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
```

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
from django.conf import settings


def edit_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.save(commit=False)

            img = Image.open(image.image)

            #added line
            img = img.convert('RGB')

            enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
            img = enhancer.enhance(2.5)

            folder_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploads')

            os.makedirs(folder_path, exist_ok=True)

            unique_filename = str(image.image)

            img.save(os.path.join(folder_path, unique_filename))

            image.image = os.path.join('uploads', unique_filename)

            image.save()

            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'edit_image.html', {'form':form})
```

Make sure to add this to the settings.py file and urls.py file.

```
settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

```
urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, even with little context provided you sorted my issue and made the code work!